# content not resizing to full width within jumbotron

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, width

i'v been trying for a couple of days to fix this on my own; but apparently this is much more complicated than expected.

What I want to achieve: I want both the iframes to use the full heigth and width of the screen. I have been abble to make the iframes use the full heigth making the div enclosing the video 100% heigth on css. But I cant seem to make it strech to use the full width.

After this I'm facing a new problem, the chat iframe is getting moved below the video iframe.

Thank you for your patience!

This is my code.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah';
  font-weight: 300;
}
.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('jumbobg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.twitchVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.twitchChat {} 
.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.nomargin {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>....</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twitch.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="jumbotron ">
    <div class="container nomargin">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twitchVideo embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=lirik" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="twitchChat">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.twitch.tv/lirik/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: .container class seems to have media queries @media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
} which is providing it fixed width.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. Now I just need to find a way to inline both iframes or something. Again thank you! ;)

Comment: I found that removing the `display: flex` from the jumbotron fixes the problem, also making the iframes `display:block` and `width: 100%`